# Do we have Node Reference : Representative node similar to the Taxonomy term: Representative node

Tags: nodes, database, views

Using **Taxonomy term: Representative node** we can get a node that represents a taxonomy term. Similarly is there a way I can get a node that represents a particular node reference field.

Use Case : I have two content types College and Teacher. For each college, I want a teacher who was recently added to the college.

Answer (score 1):

The References module doesn't seem to provide a Views relationship like that. Here is one way to achieve the required functionality in your case:

1. Add a reverse Node Reference relationship to get teacher nodes referencing the college. This will get you all teachers for each college.
2. Implement `hook_views_query_alter()` and add the extra condition utilizing a subquery:

   ```
   function mymodule_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
     switch ($view->name) {
       case 'college_teachers':         
         $expression = '
           field_college_node.nid = (
             SELECT n.nid
             FROM {field_data_field_college} fdfc
             INNER JOIN {node} n ON n.nid = fdfc.entity_id
             WHERE fdfc.entity_type = "node" AND fdfc.field_college_nid = node.nid AND n.type = "teacher" AND n.status = 1
             ORDER BY n.created DESC
             LIMIT 1)'
         $query->add_where_expression(0, $expression);
         break;
     }
   }
   ```

(The Views-generated `field_college_node` alias is a bit misleading because in fact, it will reference the teacher node, not the college one.)